# I am doing a project on financial management,i want yodlee fastlink to my project?

Tags: php, codeigniter, yodlee

I want to add yodlee fastlink to my project,i am doing it in codeigniter project.I visited the site ,but i couldn't understand properly.please any one tell me the steps to access yodlee fastlink.please

Answer (score 0):

To add the fast link to your project you can go through this document 
http://developer.yodlee.com/Fastlink_2.0/FastLink_Integration_Guide_for_Web

Also you can follow these steps to do so.

1. Get the cobrand session using the cobrand credentials and REST URL.
2. Register a new user using the cobrandSessionToken and use the generated userSession(Rsession).
3. Get the token: You need to pass cobrandSessionToken and userSessionToken and FinappId(its a constant value- 10003600)
4. Generate an HTML page which should have a form which needs to be submitted(POST) to Node URL(see example of HTML form below)

Below is the sample HTML Form you can replace the values of rsession and token  , then save it as an HTML page and just open it. This should launch the FL 2.0 successfully.

```
<div class='center processText'>Processing...</div><div><form action='<nodeURL>' method='post' id='rsessionPost'>RSession : <input type='text' name='rsession' placeholder='rsession' value='06142015_0:9d2817f2164ef0720282fd680c882b188b776d93e4af03155b0508a09ae8e274f0caab5d2d6819bee2ec69c85044410acb356807ba69ecd3e6e28643120dab61'id='rsession'/><br/>FinappId : <input type='text' name='app' placeholder='FinappId' value='10003600' id='finappId'/><br/>Redirect : <input type='text' name='redirectReq' placeholder='true/false' value='true'/><br/>Token : <input type='text' name='token' placeholder='token' value='6ea1ef4aaa1ec923aba38b911a45cbe0019a387837b0a83738ec40a8c9a24613' id='token'/><br/>Extra Params : <input type='text' name='extraParams' placeholer='Extra Params' value='' id='extraParams'/><br/></form></div><script>document.getElementById('rsessionPost').submit();</script>
```

**NOTE - You can choose any other way of FORM POST to do this.Where you POST the parameters to the Node URL**